# How to get all values from field in MongoDB using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mongodb, mongodb-query

So I'm trying to create a website using asp.net MVC and it includes a chat application that uses MongoDb for storing the messages. The problem I'm having is that I don't know how to retrieve all the messages from the collection and display them in my view.

Here's my model:

```
public class MessageViewModel
{
    public ObjectId _id { get; set; }        
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

My controller:

```
MongoClient client;
IMongoDatabase database;

    public UserController()
    {
        client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
        database = client.GetDatabase("UserMessaging");
    }

public ActionResult Messages()
    {
        var username = User.Identity.Name;
        MessageViewModel model = new MessageViewModel();

        var messageCollection = database.GetCollection<MessageViewModel>("messages");
        var messages = from m in messageCollection.AsQueryable()
                       where m.UserName == User.Identity.GetUserName()
                       select m;
        return View(messages.ToList());
    }
```

And my view:

```
<h2>Messages</h2>

<form class="navbar-form">
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="SearchUser" placeholder="Type a      user" />
 <input type="hidden" id="project-id" />
</form>

<div class="container">
 <ul id="discussion">
    @if (Model != null)
    {
        { int i = 0; }
        foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <li><p>@item.Text</p></li>
        }
    }

 </ul>
</div>
```

I'm new to MongoDb, so I'm sorry if I completely butchered it! If you need any more details just let me know.
Thank you!

Comment: Can you explain what happens? Do you get nothing back? Some? Does your find work in the shell / your fav editor ? Is it in your Controller but not in your frontend

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! My view loads up just fine, and a connection is made with the database. I don't know if I get anything back. Yes, my find does work in the shell. And I don't know what you mean by your last question, sorry. Hope this helps! @HoefMeistert

Comment: What i mean is does your code in your controller the "messages" var contains something or is it empty

Comment: @HoefMeistert It contains stuff. It successfully gets the values from the database but it won't display the results in the view

Comment: Figured out the problem! The line var messageCollection = database.GetCollection<MessageViewModel>("messages") in my controller was supposed to be var messageCollection = database.GetCollection<MessageViewModel>("message")! It was only a typo! Thanks for the help though @HoefMeistert!

Comment: No problem, glad is was something small :)

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the problem! The line:

```
var messageCollection = database.GetCollection<MessageViewModel>("messages")
```

in my controller was supposed to be:

```
var messageCollection = database.GetCollection<MessageViewModel>("message")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, if you are using the MongoDb 2.0 driver (and async), you could use the native Find() and it would look something like this:

```
var messageCollection = database.GetCollection<MessageViewModel>("message")
var results = messageCollection.Find(x => true).ToListAsync();
```

This would return all items in the collection